# How to access Jamara 038300 qcr?

Tags: microcontroller

I've got a Jamara 38300 qcr quadrocopter but not controller for it. I want to control it with a ps3 controller, an app or just via windows Bluetooth. How can I achieve this?
I know that the quadrocopter sends with a 2.4 GHz frequency and the on board microcontroller is a SMT8S005K6.
Can I just catch the signal from the transmitter so that I know which exact types of orders I have to send and try out some or do I have to connect to the microcontroller via a SL-Link which is used to program the SMT8 and get the code which is already on the micro (something like reverse engineering) ?
I don't really want to buy a "normal" controller for quadrocopter.